# JsHint {a} is not defined

Tags: javascript, jshint, jscs

I need to disable rule 117 for JsHint for a specific line, at the moment I am using `/*jshint -W117 */` with no success.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
    _createDom: function () {
        //jscs:disable maximumLineLength
        var template = '';

        /*jshint -W117 */
        template += dojoConfig.app.hasTools ? '<div id="panelDevelopment"></div>' : '';
        template += '<div id="boundingBoxes">';

        //jscs:enable maximumLineLength
    }
};
```

NOTES: It seems working when `/*jshint -W117 */` is placed at the beginning of the JS file and not inside my method.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing I couldn't get this to work either; might need to open a bug.  Disabling this rule specifically didn't work when I tried, though others seemed to work in the same context.

As an alternative, you can specify a white list of global variables via `/* globals dojoConfig */` at the top of the file [as an inline configuration](http://jshint.com/docs/#inline-configuration); it might be better to explicitly declare any undefined variables than to enable them entirely anyway.  You could also do the same at the project [as a linter option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals).